# Penalty for interfering with the path of the cue ball?

Tags: rules, snooker

In snooker, what is the penalty for interfering with the path of the cue ball?

I assume it must be more than 7 points because let's say a player hits a shot and he sees the cue ball heading for the black which is not on, then it is a seven point foul if he hits it, so let's say he sticks his cue in front of the cue ball and deflects it, what is the penalty?

I guess the same question could apply in any situation where the frame is in jeopardy if the cue ball gets into position. In other words, let's say that if the cue ball lands in favorable position for the other player, then you will lose the frame. No penalty is big enough, because you will lose the frame anyway, so you might as well foul to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

Section 4 of the [Official Rules](http://www.wpbsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/official-rules-of-the-game.pdf) allows the referee a *lot* of discretion in this kind of matter:

> In the event of [...] any conduct by a Player which in the opinion of the referee is wilfully or persistently unfair [...] the referee shall either:
>
> (v) warn the Player that in the event of any such further conduct the
> frame will be awarded to his opponent; or
> (vi) award the frame to his opponent; or
> (vii) in the event that the conduct is sufficiently serious, award the game
> to his opponent.

For any professional players, I'd imagine that this kind of behaviour would also result in sanctions from the [WPBSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Professional_Billiards_and_Snooker_Association).